# Regex to detect body of the arduino function

Tags: javascript, regex

Given a dummy function as such:

```
#include "DigiKeyboard.h"
        
void setup() {
            
#start_shift_3

DigiKeyboard.sendKeyStroke(0);

#end_shift_3

}
        
   void loop() {

  DigiKeyboard.delay(2000);

     }
```

I tried to get the content of the **Setup function** between the brackets and I tried

`/[setup]+[(][a-zA-Z0-9=',]+[)][{]\n(.+?)\n+\s+[}]/gs`

To get the result I want

```
#start_shift_3

DigiKeyboard.sendKeyStroke(0);

#end_shift_3
```

The problem is that the code was not written correctly because it works in the Regex site

But it doesn't work with javascript code and I think the reason is

**regex single line flag /s**

I searched a lot and read on Stackoverflow and the answers are not appropriate for the situation

[My Regex](https://regexr.com/6v190)

So even though the code works there, it won't work with JavaScript

```js
var string = `


#include "DigiKeyboard.h"

void setup(){

#start_shift_3

DigiKeyboard.sendKeyStroke(0);

#end_shift_3

}

   void loop() {

  DigiKeyboard.delay(2000);

     }
        

`;



const regex = new RegExp("[setup]+[(][)][{]\n(.+?)\n+\s+[}]');

console.log(string.match(regex) == null);
```

Comment: wouldn't that fail if there is `}` inside the function?

Comment: @ITgoldman I don't know, but I think I've read before. This can be overcome by making it \}
But in my case } will not be used inside the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex extracts the content within `{` ... `}` of `setup`:

```js
var string = `

#include "DigiKeyboard.h"

void setup(){

#start_shift_3

DigiKeyboard.sendKeyStroke(0);

#end_shift_3

}

   void loop() {

  DigiKeyboard.delay(2000);

     }
`;

const m = string.match(/\bsetup\s*\(\)\s*\{\s*([^\}]*)/);
console.log(m ? m[1] : '(no match)');
```

Explanation of regex:

- `\b` -- word boundary
- `setup` -- expect literal `setup` string
- `\s*\(\)\s*` -- scan over optional whitespace, `()`, whitespace
- `\{\s*` -- scan over opening `{` and optional whitespace
- `([^\}]*)` -- capture group scanning over everything not a closing `}`

Note that this will fail if your setup function contains curly braces. In that case you would need a proper language parser, or a multi-step regex that annotates the nesting level of the curly braces, so that you can identify the proper closing brace of the function.

Comment: I won't need to add curly braces inside the function so this is a perfect answer

Thank you for the very useful answer